# Swift uploading image, response from server says file wasn't an image?

Tags: php, json, swift, alamofire

Working on a Swift project, and apparently the file I'm uploading isn't an image. I'm also using the Alamofire utility.

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    print ("MARK -- UUID is " + uuid)
    let image = imageView.image

    Alamofire.upload(.POST, "{RETRACTED}", multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in
        if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.6) {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: uuid, fileName: uuid + ".png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }
        }, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.data)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print ("JSON \(JSON)")
                        self.displayAlert("Uploaded!", message: "{RETRACTED}", responseButtonText: "{RETRACTED}")
                    }
                }

            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })
```

Here's the JSON response (I also have the PHP server side code if needed):

JSON {
    response = "That file wasn't an image (Only .png and .jpg/.jpeg images are accepted). The type is ";
    responseCode = 0;
}

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an jpg image, but specifying mime type for png. Change mime type to "image/jpeg" or send a png file.